# How can I use Expect to enter a password for a Perl script?

Tags: perl, expect

I wish to automatically enter a password while running an install script. I have invoked the install script using the backticks in Perl. Now my issue is how do I enter that password using `expect` or something else?

```
my $op = `install.sh -f my_conf -p my_ip -s my_server`;
```

When the above is executed, a password line is printed:

```
Enter password for the packagekey:
```

In the above line I wish to enter the password.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

use [Expect.pm](https://metacpan.org/pod/Expect).

This module is especially tailored for programatic control of applications which require user feedback

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Expect;

my $expect      = Expect->new;
my $command     = 'install.sh';
my @parameters  = qw(-f my_conf -p my_ip -s my_server);
my $timeout     = 200;
my $password    = "W31C0m3";

$expect->raw_pty(1);  
$expect->spawn($command, @parameters)
    or die "Cannot spawn $command: $!\n";

$expect->expect($timeout,
                [   qr/Enter password for the packagekey:/i, #/
                    sub {
                        my $self = shift;
                        $self->send("$password\n");
                        exp_continue;
                    }
                ]);
```

Answer (score 3):

If the program reads the password from standard input, you can just pipe it in:

```
`echo password | myscript.sh (...)`
```

If not, Expect or PTYs.

Comment: It doesn't work because if use any special character in your password.         
    sample error message                                              In string, @ug now must be written as \@ug at gsx.pl line 5, near "echo  RRRRR@ug"
Global symbol "@ug" requires explicit package name at gsx.pl line 5

Comment: If you've got special characters in your password, you find out the proper way to escape them in context. It exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the password in a file and while running the install script, read the password from the file.