# Password less telnet to remote server and execute commands and retrieve the details

Tags: shell, perl, telnet

Currently am logging into the server using telnet on the command line without a password:

```
telnet -afl root servername
```

I need a script which should connect to server using telnet without a password, run a command like `wc -l`, and retrieve the result of this command.

I tried using expect, but it is prompting for a password, throwing an error. Can someone suggest a way this can be done?

Comment: Is there not a password that you can use? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366751/how-can-i-use-expect-to-enter-a-password-for-a-perl-script

Comment: Using `telnet` without any authentication is obviously extremely insecure. Can you switch to `ssh` instead and disable `telnet` access altogether?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Net::Telnet;

my $t = new Net::Telnet (Timeout  => 10);

$t->open('nethack.alt.org');

$t->waitfor( -match => '/Quit/' );

$t->print( 'w' );

print $t->waitfor( -match => '/Watch which game/' );
```